# How to add root Project as classpath in Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

In JAVA eclipse, the main class of the java project is defined as one of the class in the JAR of the 'lib' folder, and the root project (fooBar) is added as a dependency in the classpath.

This can be acheived in eclipse by simply adding the root project in the classpath. However, how do we add the dependency of the root project in gradle?

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':fooBar');
}


> Project with path ':fooBar' could not be found in root project 'fooBar'.
```

The following is the project structure:

```
fooBar
-src/main/java
-src/test/java
-JRE System Library
-gradle
--wrapper
--launch.gradle
-lib
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle
-gradle-apps.settings
-gradle.properties
-gradlew
-gradlew.bat
```

Comment: @artem Can you please show your project structure. This is not clear. How many projects you have?

Comment: If you dont mind, please give the project structure. This description is not clear.

Comment: i have 1 project, project structure seen above

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got your point. First of all I have a doubt. Why are you adding

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':fooBar');
}
```

this entry in build.gradle of fooBar project? This can cause cyclic dependency and results in build failure.
So I guess remove the above entry from build.gradle of fooBar project.

And please add the below code in your settings.gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = 'fooBar'

include ':fooBar'
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

As far as the project method is concerned, the root project has no name. So this is the syntax in the subproject's build.gradle:

dependencies {
  compile project(':')
}

However, it is rarely a good idea to do this. It is too easy to end up with circular dependencies. Most multi-module projects have a separate "main" projects (called something like "main", "core" or "base"), and other modules can easily depend on that using compile project(':core') or whatever.

(Originally answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44914700/3195526).)