# How to create Gradle multi-module project

Tags: gradle, multi-module

I'me creating a TAF from scratch using Gradle and decided to make it multi-module. So I've created 'base-project' with build.gradle file looking like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // common dependencies for all modules
}
```

I've created 2 modules using IDE :
testng-module and junit-module

So my base project's settings gradle file looks like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'base-project'
include 'testng-module'
include 'junit-module'
```

So for my junit module's build.gradle file looks like :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base-project')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But I've got an error:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':junit-module'.

> Project with path ':base-project' could not be found in project ':junit-module'.

What can be the reason. I didn't create settings.gradle file for junit-module, because as I far as I understand it all project dependencies should be set in base project's settings.gradle file. I would also like to mention, that I created modules in IDE, not subprojects [image: (module creation in IDE)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How add gradle to subproject root project as dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576750/how-add-gradle-to-subproject-root-project-as-dependency)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. So the hierarchy in my project looks like this:

Comment: Are you sure it didn't work? What happens when you try changing `implementation project(':base-project')` to `implementation project(':')`?

Comment: @aSemy, sorry, I've just retried it, and it worked. Thanks. The project compiled, but I can't use dependencies, that are written in base-project's build.gradle file in junit-module...

Comment: If the base project requires any consumer also depends on some other dependencies then you can use [`api()` instead of `implementation()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44413952/4161471), but note that it's usually better to use `implementation()`, otherwise you'll end up with dependencies leaking everywhere.

Comment: oh, can't edit text here as I would like